# Using accumulate and/or cumsum properly for projections

Tags: r, data-analysis, cumsum, cross-join, accumulate

I need to project each *Z, W, Y* value of each row in df1. To do this, I will use the growth rates in *B* from df2.

```
df1:
X    Y  year    Z      W      V
abc ab  2020    0.1  0.7    1.3
abc cd  2020    0.2  0.8    1.4
efg ef  2020    0.3  0.9    1.5
efg gh  2020    0.4  1      1.6

df2:
year    B       
2021    0.05    
2022    0.063   
2023    0.049   
2024    0.061   
2025    0.057
```

I understand that a cross join might solve the problem. However, before that I need to be sure that the precious value is used for the next calculation.

I expect something like this:

```
from df1:
X    Y  year    Z      W      V
abc ab  2020    0.1    0.7    1.3

df3: (edited)
year    B       C       D       E       X   Y
2020    0       0.1000  0.7000  1.3000  abc ab 
2021    0.05    0.1050  0.7350  1.3650  abc ab 
2022    0.063   0.1116  0.7813  1.4510  abc ab 
2023    0.049   0.1171  0.8196  1.5221  abc ab 
2024    0.061   0.1242  0.8696  1.6149  abc ab 
2025    0.057   0.1313  0.9192  1.7070  abc ab  

Formulas for df3 (edited)
1    year   B       C               D               E
2    2020   0       0.1             0.7             1.3
3    2021   0.05    =+C2*($B$3+1)   =+D2*($B$3+1)   =+E2*($B$3+1)
4    2022   0.063   =+C3*($B$4+1)   =+D3*($B$4+1)   =+E3*($B$4+1)
5    2023   0.049   =+C4*($B$5+1)   =+D4*($B$5+1)   =+E4*($B$5+1)
6    2024   0.061   =+C5*($B$6+1)   =+D5*($B$6+1)   =+E5*($B$6+1)
7    2025   0.057   =+C6*($B$7+1)   =+D6*($B$7+1)   =+E6*($B$7+1)
```

To get df3, I have tried:

```
df3 <- df2 %>% mutate(example2 = accumulate(B, ~ 0.1 * ( .x +1)))

df3 <- df2 %>% mutate(example2 = cumsum(accumulate(B, ~ 0.1 * ( .x +1))))
```

The outcome is still not the expected.

At the end, I would need to pass it into the cross join and across functions, something like this:

```
df3 <- mutate(cross_join(df1[-3], df2), across(Z:V)*(H), H = NULL)
```

Comment: what does `$B$3` stand for? seems like  its a constant value? Also what is C2? where is C1?

Comment: are your results correct? ie is there something wrong with your `B` column.  IF you had `B` as `df2$B <- c(0.05, 0.063, 0.063, 0.063)` then everything works out: ie `df1$Z[1] * cumprod(1+df2$B)`  or even `df1$W[1] * cumprod(1+df2$B)`   or even `df1$V[1] * cumprod(1+df2$B)` . either you meant to use `df$B[3]` or some values are wrong in your resulting table above

Comment: @Onyambu, you are right. I introduced a bug in the formula. I have edited now. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a first take on doing it. There's likely a simpler way (but alas, there always is):

```
# first, we do a few things to df2
# 1. we add a 2020 column
# 2. we transform the interest rate to 1 + the interest rate (to enable the cumulative product function to work
# 3. we use the cumprod function to turn the B column into the cumulative products of B + 1
df2 <- df2 %>% 
  add_row(year = 2020, B = 0, .before = 1) %>%
  mutate(B = cumprod(B + 1))

# remove the year from df1, because it's unnecessary, and we'd have to remove it later anyway
df1 <- df1 %>%
    select(-year)

# df3
cross_join(df1, df2) %>%
    mutate(C = Z * B,
        D = W * B,
        E = V * B) %>%
    select(year, B, C, D, E, X, Y)

# A tibble: 24 × 7
    year     B     C     D     E X     Y    
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
 1  2020  1    0.1   0.7    1.3  abc   ab   
 2  2021  1.05 0.105 0.735  1.37 abc   ab   
 3  2022  1.12 0.112 0.781  1.45 abc   ab   
 4  2023  1.17 0.117 0.820  1.52 abc   ab   
 5  2024  1.24 0.124 0.870  1.61 abc   ab   
 6  2025  1.31 0.131 0.919  1.71 abc   ab   
 7  2020  1    0.2   0.8    1.4  abc   cd   
 8  2021  1.05 0.21  0.84   1.47 abc   cd   
 9  2022  1.12 0.223 0.893  1.56 abc   cd   
10  2023  1.17 0.234 0.937  1.64 abc   cd   
# ℹ 14 more rows
```

Update: simpler way:

```
df2 %>%
    add_row(year = 2020, B = 0, .before = 1) %>%
    cross_join(df1) %>%
    group_by(X, Y) %>%
    mutate(across(c(Z, W, V), ~ . * cumprod(B + 1))) %>%
    rename("C" = Z, "D" = W, "E" = V) %>%
    ungroup()
```

Comment: this does not produce the expected results

Comment: I think there might be an issue with the example OP gave- in C, 2023, I get the answer `0.1170841` when I do it by hand (`0.1 * 1.05 * 1.063 * 1.049`)

Comment: maybe I have misunderstood the question though! What do you think @Onyambu

Comment: OP is using `B[3]` across everything. I do not understand why that is the case, yet they start by `B[1]` ie `0.1* 1.05 *1.063 *1.063 *1.063 *1.063 ....`

Comment: oh wait! I think I get it now

Comment: yeah we both realised it at the same time haha

Comment: OP is using B3 (in a spreadsheet I assume, which I think would correspond to the Z = 0.1 cell

Comment: I had commented on the post regarding this an hour ago.

Comment: I missed this haha 

Comment: it seems like another case of, "did OP produce faulty code or are they really wanting what they say they want" hey @Onyambu?

Comment: The comments should enable them decide on what they want

Comment: Dear both, I introduce a bug in the formula section. I just edited.

Comment: I just checked both answers and 2nd one works as expected (Update: simpler way). I really appreciate it.